# How to auto save html textarea without button?

Tags: php, html

I have a textarea in my html like this:

```
<textarea id="area1"></textarea>
```

When visitors copy/paste or type something in this area i want it to save to a txt file without the visitor having to click any button.

Looked all over the web but can't find any solution.

Comment: You could use **AJAX** for this.

Comment: When would it be safe to save while typing? You can do oninput or onkeyup ajax with debouncing

Comment: @Wimanicesir LOL. Linking to the site that was the reason for SO's existence ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write `JS` function, that saves info in `.txt` file. Let's say, function name is `saveToTxt()`. Then trigger that function `onChange`:

```
<textarea id="area1" onChange="saveToTxt(this);"></textarea>
```

**EDITED**

Assume that, `saveToTxt()` is something like that:

```
<script>
function saveToTxt(fld) {
    const textAreaValue = fld.value;
    // then use textArea variable as container of textarea-content
    // and then treat it as you want.
}
</script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan - You can simply edit my answer or first write it in comment section, before use downVote, isn't it right?

Comment: @mplungjan - That is what I call COLLABORATION :)

Comment: oninput is still what I would use myself

Comment: Does not work for me... can i do this in php?

Comment: Or how do i call the php script to actually save the data to a txt file on the server?

Answer (score 1):

This example show how to save content automatically 2s after changing. It can prevent from doing save for every character typed.

```js
var t;
function save() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('All changes saved'); // save here
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<textarea onchange="save();" onkeyup="save();"></textarea>
```

Comment: does not work for me... maybe i have to try php

Comment: Of course you need a php to save your content, javascript is just for passing parameters to your php

Comment: Well i looked all over but can not find any script example... i am not good at scripting so was kinda looking for a live or working example.

Comment: So far i got this... how do i call the php script?

Comment: Search for jQuery and Ajax